# Programmatically create plist

Tags: ios, export, nsdictionary, plist

I have created a plist that is being used by my app, but I have recently decided that I would like to restructure the list. Currently the plist is a dictionary whose values are dictionaries whose values are arrays whose values are strings. However, I realize now that I actually need those strings at the deepest level of the index path to be dictionaries, one of the values of which will be the original string. The plist is quite large and changing each value manually will take more time than I have. The operation I need to perform on each string is very uniform and programmable, and I have written the code to convert the dictionary that is the current plist to the dictionary that I require it to be. Now I am just wondering how to bring that programmatically altered dictionary "out into the real world", i.e., export it so that the data in my current plist is reformatted to my liking.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Run your app in simulator. You will find the file in `/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/<version>/Applications/<app id>/<path in app sanbox>/<filename>`
2. Run your app on a device and use the Xcode Organizer to download the sandbox files from your app to your computer. Find the file in the extracted files.

Comment: Thank you, could you possibly give me an example of some specific code to do this?

Comment: You said you already had code to create the file and just wanted to know how to get the file. You don't need code to access the created file.